# NuxtJs Vuex | Unexpected token when I trying to use ...mapGetters or ...mapActions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm new in NuxtJs.
When I try to call ...mapGetter I receive this error above and I find nothing about.
I try to follow the nuxt guide, but I can't find nothing about how to use mapGetters.

This is the shell error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (37:4)                                                                                 friendly-errors 21:58:14

  35 | 
  36 |   computed() {
> 37 |     ...mapGetters(['currentUser'])
     |     ^
  38 |   },
  39 | 
  40 |   methods: {

                                                                                                                      friendly-errors 21:58:14
 @ ./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-227 1:243-246 1:248-472 1:248-472
 @ ./pages/index.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

This is my store code:

```js
// store/user.js

export const state = () => ({
  user: {},
})

export const getters = {
  currentUser: (state) => {
    return state.user
  },
}

export const actions = {
  doLogin: ({ commit }, params) => {
    const mock = { username: params.username, token: '123' }

    commit('setUser', mock)
  },
}

export const mutations = {
  setUser: (state, user) => {
    state.user = user
  },
}
```

Comment: `computed: { ...mapGetters(` etc - i.e. computed is not a function, it's just a property - https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Answer (score 0):

First of fall, computed is a property, not a function

```
export default {
   computed: {
      /***/
   }
}
```

And Second, You are using module ( user, in your case ) system to initiate the store. You also need to mention the module name when you are mapping the store ( expect for index.js ), like so

```
computed: {
     ...mapGetters("user", ["currentUser"])
   }
```